# Android Eclipse with ADT: An error has occurred. see the log file

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-gradle-plugin

I have Eclipse Juno with Android ADT bundle, I installed the Gradle plugin from the site http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

after setup it asked for restarting eclipse then it didn't open the IDE, it showed the message

> An error has occurred. see the log file [path to the log file]

the log file is:

> !SESSION Tue Aug 19 23:31:08 EET 2014
>   ------------------------------------------ !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2014-08-19 23:31:08.557 !MESSAGE
>   Could not find extension: org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications
>   !SESSION 2014-08-19 23:31:08.497
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035 java.version=1.7.0_13
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product Command-line arguments: 
>   -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-08-19 23:31:09.100 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications not found.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE One or
>   more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints
>   are not resolved: !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.core 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core_7.1.0.201202111925.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.112 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.200.v20120522-1148.jar
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.team.ui 2 0 2014-08-19
>
> org.eclipse.wst.xsd.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.search_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58
>   [274] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ant.launching_1.0.200.v20120530-1204 [283] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.launching 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.6.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ant.launching 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.221 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ant.launching 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.221
>   !MESSAGE Missing imported package
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui_3.3.300.v20120522-1651 [329] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.0.600.v20130116-050536 [330] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.0.200.v20130116-050536 [331] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE Missing host org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.3.v20130121-145325 [332] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.223
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   optionally required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_1.5.0.v20120523-1543 [333]
>   was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.6.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.101.v20120913-153601 [334] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.100.v20120530-1425 [335] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug_[3.7.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.6.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.224 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_[1.3.0,2.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.search_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.100.v20120523-1543 [337] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.225 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.compare_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core_[3.6.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core_3.7.100.v20120523-1257 [338] was not
>   resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.6.101.v20130111-183046 [341] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.launching 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.launching 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.launching 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.launching 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug_[3.7.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.8.2.v20130107-165834 [342] was not resolved.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.search_[3.7.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.226 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.6.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.compare_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE
>   Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_[3.4.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing
>   required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_[1.4.0,2.0.0).
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.0.400.v20120523-1955 [355] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.ide.application 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.2.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi
>   2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [357] was
>   not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.6.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0). !SUBENTRY 1
>   org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core_3.6.0.201407080553-RELEASE
>   [366] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.227 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.227
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.228 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jem.util_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core_2.6.1. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.codehaus.groovy_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.228 !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.m2e.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0
>   2014-08-19 23:31:10.228 !MESSAGE Bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui_3.6.0.201407080553-RELEASE
>   [368] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.228 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY
>   2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.228
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.externaltools_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.229 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.ant.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.229
>   !MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle
>   org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.229
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.229 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.229
>   !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors_0.0.0.
>   !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE
>   Bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview_3.6.0.201407080553-RELEASE
>   [369] was not resolved. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui_0.0.0. !SUBENTRY 2
>   org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.taskview 2 0 2014-08-19
>   23:31:10.230 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle
>   org.eclipse.debug.core_0.0.0.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-08-19 23:31:10.238 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Application
>   "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The
>   applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate,
>   org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool.  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall OPENJDK.
Here it is.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```